# Apache2 localhost keeps crashing?

Tags: html, apache, raspberry-pi, apache2, chromium

I've been hired to use a raspberry pi to create a kind of "lobby kiosk" in the lobby of the company I'm working for for my high school internship. On startup, the raspberry pi will display 3 items; a constantly looping video of a presentation that sums up the goals and services of the company, the weather, and a news bar.

To accomplish this, I decided to use a locally hosted apache2 website that would be opened in kiosk mode on boot. To provide the news and weather, I used website widgets; the ones from momentaryreview.com and weatherwidget.io, respectively, and the video was provided using  html5 tags with the source being a .mp4 file stored on the pi. To continuously update the news and weather, I set up the website to refresh every time the presentation finishes, so as to not disrupt the loop. I also have some CSS code to hide the scrollbar. Lastly, I set up a cronjob to reboot the pi every day at midnight.

This setup works fairly well, except every hour or two, the website will randomly crash, displaying the typical "Aw snap! we couldn't access this webpage" error. Nothing appears in the error logs, and there isn't unusual appears in the access logs either; in addition, when you refresh the page, everything goes back to normal. Though, of course I can't have the kiosk needing to be refreshed every couple hours; it has to be running all day without any intervention. What could be causing these crashes?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's my code:

```
<html >

<!--CSS block to set design parameters for the website -->
<style type="text/css">
.WebContainer{
    width:100%;
    min-width:1850px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:1075px;

} 
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;

}
<!-- sets website dimensions to 1920x1080p;-->
body {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  background-color: #FFF;

}

<!-- makes scrollbar invisible -->
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
</style>


<!--Displays "Welcome to (Company) on top of page & sets background color -->
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center; font-family:sans-serif;">Welcome to (Company)</h1>
<body style="background-color: skyblue;"></body>

</body>


<!--takes weather information from weatherwidget.io and displays it on the website -->
<a class="weatherwidget-io" 
href="https://forecast7.com/en/35d79n78d78/(location)/?unit=us" 
data-label_1="LOCATION" 
data-label_2="WEATHER" 
data-theme="original" 
>LOCATION WEATHER</a> 
<script>
!function(d,s,id)
{
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if(!d.getElementById(id))
        {
        js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
        js.src='https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
}
        (document,'script','weatherwidget-io-js');
</script>


<!-- takes news from the momentaryreview news widget-->
<iframe 
style="background-color: #ffffff;" 
src="https://momentaryreview.com/widget"
name="News_widget" 
class="iframe"
width="20%" 
height="875" 
frameborder="1" 
marginwidth="0" 
marginheight="0"
scrolling="no"
></iframe>


<!-- displays the powerpoint on the website as an mp4; edit these to make the video display normally on smaller screens -->
<video width="1500" height="875" autoplay muted loop> 
<source src="IntroPresentationFinal.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>


<!-- refreshes the page every loop of the presentation, which is 143 seconds long long --> 
<meta   
http-equiv="refresh" 
content = "142"
>

<body>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think this is more likely to be a chromium issue than with apache. This might be relevant: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=265558. Do you have any extensions on the browser such as the h264 extension? Apparently that can occasionally cause issues. Possibly an alternative could be to reload just the iframe instead of the whole page

Comment: I actually do have the h264 extension; I'll remove that. Also, how would you go about just reloading the iframe? Just moving the http=equiv refresh to where it's set up?

Comment: Since your iframe is from a different domain you would probably only be able to use `document.getElementById('iframeid').src = document.getElementById('iframeid').src` in javascript

Comment: Ok, I'll try implementing that. Thanks for the help! Let's hope this fixes the crashing.